# PHP providing parameter visible only inslide class

Tags: php, oop, visibility

I might not grasp nature of PHP OOP system so that's maybe not impossible but let me ask is there a way to create parameter that's accesible only by methods of this class?

I want to craete 'local' class parameters that are only visible inside it, because now if I create object: `$data = new MyClass();` it is going to return:

```
object(MyClass)#1 (2) {
  ["secret"]=> string(33) "It should be not readable/visible"
  }
}
```

How to make `object->secret` not visible in `$data`?

Comment: `private $attribute = 'whatever';` It is actually the abcs of oop in almost every programming language

Comment: @Brewal that still doesn't prevent it from being read during var_dump() calls... (I'm not sure what exactly OP wants)

Comment: I hope it does not. `var_dump` is for debug... It would be really anoying otherwise

Comment: If `var_dump` can access it, every other part of my code does don't you get it I want to hide it?

Comment: `var_dump` is part of php core for debugging purpose. Be sure that your private variables are only accessible from the class itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class myClass {
    private $myvariable;

    private function myFunction() {

    }
}
```

This makes it so only $myVariable and myFunction can be accessed within myClass

Comment: But when I do so I get `Call to a member function myFunction() on a non-object in` when doing `$data = new myClass();
var_dump($data->myFunction());`

Comment: In my comment I talk about code that you provided - test It and you will get error `Call to a member function...`

Comment: You can't call this function as it is private

Comment: But when it's public I still get it.

Comment: [30-Sep-2014 01:47:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Call to private method myClass::myFunction() from context '' in /Users/nicholasyoung/Desktop/index.php on line 15

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php - Do you guys even read the documentation? Why would a function print out when using var_dump? Its not returning anything.

Comment: if you return something it will print it out

Comment: I think I know the doc well enough. Thank you. But I really don't understand what the OP wants

Comment: All he wanted to know what how do make things private: http://codepad.org/NX4rrTEc

Comment: Then why your answer is not yet accepted ? I think `var_dump` disturbs

Comment: "How to make object->secret not visible in $data?" Dur dur dur. I'm done fighting it answered his question its his choice if he accepts it or not.